# @click on parent div not firing when pressing child button

Tags: vue.js

I have made a custom number input box component and want it to activate on click. The component consists of 3 elements, two buttons (for decreasing and increasing the number value), and an input, where the number is displayed and can manually be changed. The problem is that the `@click` of the parent div (`.numberField`) only fires when clicking the input box, not when the buttons are clicked.

Because the input box seemed to be working I have tried changing the button elements to `input[type=button]` elements, but that failed.

I have checked when `@click` of the child elements (the two buttons and the input) fire, and confirmed that all of them behave in the same way (they don't fire on the initial click that sets `:disabled="false"` on each of them)

My `Vue` version is `3.7.0` if that matters

```
<template>
  <div class="numberField" @click="fieldClicked">
    <button @click="stepDown()" :disabled="disabled" class="left">
      &minus;
    </button>
    <input
      v-model="value"
      type="number"
      :max="max"
      :min="min"
      :step="step"
      :disabled="disabled">
    <button @click="stepUp()" :disabled="disabled" class="right">
      &plus;
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NumberField',
  props: {
    defaultValue: Number,
    max: Number,
    min: Number,
    step: Number,
    disabled: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.defaultValue,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      this.value = Math.min(this.max, Math.max(this.min, this.value));
    },
  },
  methods: {
    stepDown() {
      this.value -= this.step;
    },
    stepUp() {
      this.value += this.step;
    },
    fieldClicked(event) {
      // @click.stop will stop all clicks from propagating; we will only stop clicks when the field is active
      if (!this.disabled) event.stopPropagation()
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.numberField {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 8em;
}

.left {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2em;
}

.right {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.2em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2em;
}

input, button {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

This is a summary of how I'm using this component:

```
<div class="item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="toggleItem(item.id)" :class="{ active: activeItems[item.id] }">
  <h1>{{ item.name }}, some other elements irrelevant are here too</h1>
  <NumberField
    :defaultValue="item.amount"
    :max="item.amount"
    :min="1"
    :step="1"
    :disabled="!activeItems[item.id]"></NumberField>
</div>
```

`toggleItem(id)` toggles the boolean value of `activeItems[item.id]`. The NumberField is disabled when the item is inactive.

My expectation would be that clicking on any of the child elements of `.numberField` would fire the `@click` of `.numberField`, which (only if the item is inactive) then gets propagated to the `@click` of `.item`, but this only seems to be the case when clicking the `input[type=number]`.

I would appreciate any help, I'm absolutely lost!

Comment: to achieve that you should use $emit/$on events, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Could you confirm that `disabled` is set to `true` when you are observing the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by _parent element_? That div with `numberField` class?

By the way, your `fieldClicked` misses `event` parameter.

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I'm unsure how that would help. I would not be able to emit an event because \@click does not work on those buttons since they are disabled

Comment: @skirtle Yes, the NumberField instance I'm working with initially has disabled: true. When clicking on the input field it changes to false, when clicking either of the buttons it doesn't. It changes to false because the `@click` of `.numberField` is propagated to a `div` (the parent of the NumberField instance) that changes the value passed as the `disabled` prop

Comment: @DawidLoranc Yes, that is what I meant, I will add it to the question. Also added event as a parameter :) Thank you!

Comment: Would be nice if you could you also add an example of NumberField component usage.

Comment: @DawidLoranc I have added some code and explained how I'm using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<button>` with a `disabled` attribute set will not fire click events. If the event doesn't fire on the `<button>` then it won't propagate to the `<div>` either.

In your case a simple workaround would be to put `pointer-events: none` on your buttons so that the button is skipped altogether. The `<div>` will just receive the click directly, as though the button wasn't even there.

```js
const NumberField = {
  name: 'NumberField',
  template: `
    <div class="numberField" @click="fieldClicked">
      <button @click="stepDown()" :disabled="disabled" class="left">
        &minus;
      </button>
      <input
        v-model="value"
        type="number"
        :max="max"
        :min="min"
        :step="step"
        :disabled="disabled">
      <button @click="stepUp()" :disabled="disabled" class="right">
        &plus;
      </button>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    defaultValue: Number,
    max: Number,
    min: Number,
    step: Number,
    disabled: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.defaultValue,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      this.value = Math.min(this.max, Math.max(this.min, this.value));
    },
  },
  methods: {
    stepDown() {
      this.value -= this.step;
    },
    stepUp() {
      this.value += this.step;
    },
    fieldClicked(event) {
      console.log('here')
      // @click.stop will stop all clicks from propagating; we will only stop clicks when the field is active
      if (!this.disabled) event.stopPropagation()
    },
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    NumberField
  }
})
```

```css
.numberField {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 8em;
}

.left {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2em;
}

.right {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.2em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2em;
}

input, button {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <number-field :defaultValue="7" :step="1" :min="0" :max="10" disabled></number-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I read your explanation it makes a lot of sense, I guess I was confused because the input _did_ work. Anyway, thanks again. Have a great day!

Comment: TLDR: Add `pointer-events: none` to your disabled button or input
Thanks a lot @skirtle